# Performance of HashMap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have to process 450 unique strings about 500 million times. Each string has unique integer identifier. There are two options for me to use.

1. I can append the identifier with the string and on arrival of the
   string I can split the string to get the identifier and use it.
2. I can store the 450 strings in `HashMap<String, Integer>` and on
   arrival of the string, I can query `HashMap` to get the identifier.

Can someone suggest which option will be more efficient in terms of processing?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please clarify more what each option means.  Where do the identifiers come from? What do you mean by "process" them 500 million times?  Are the identifiers from a dense set (i.e. contiguous integers, say 1-450)? If not, what does the distribution look like.  Lots of information is missing here, and that information will be very important in deciding which data structure to use.

Comment: Couldn't you also create a class with two fields, `theString` and `theIdentifier`?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter which way you do it.  The overheads of "getting" the string and/or processing them after the lookup are likely to vastly exceed the overheads of the string "identification" process.  (And if not ... you need to explain the larger context.)

Comment: Suppose there 450 unique strings each has a unique int identifier. Now there is a String vector of length 450 * 5000000000. each entry in this vector is one of the 450 strings. I have to process this vector. I hope it is clear now

Comment: It seems that you have a "real world problem" - your actual task is to process 500 million strings. In Java, it is quite hard to do micro benchmarks for performance because the dynamic HotSpot JVM can have a different performance for the same code depending on how you use it. But here - my advice: just implement it in both ways and test it. Both options are easy and take little time to implement and you'll have very good performance data to analyse. Just use the stopwatch on your smartphone if you have no tools.

Comment: The problem with splitting the string, if I understand you, is that you create 1 billion new strings, and that's a lot of work for GC.  I would guess that looking a string up in the Map is significantly cheaper than creating and GCing two strings.  If you could figure out how to use the prefix scheme without having to split the string then it would be a different matter.

Comment: Stupid question:  Why can't you just send the "identifier" and look up the string in a Map (or, if the identifier space is compact enough, in an array)?  Why do you need to send the string at all?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the sizes of the strings, etc.

You can do all sorts of things.

You can use a binary search to get the index in a list, and at that index is the identifier.

You can hash just the first 2 characters, rather than the entire string, that would likely be faster than the binary search, assuming the strings have an OK distribution.

You can use the first character, or first two characters, if they're unique as a "perfect index" in to 255 or 65K large array that points to the identifier.

Also, if your identifier is numeric, it's better to pre-calculate that, rather than convert it on the fly all the time. Text -> Binary is actually rather expensive (Binary -> Text is worse). So it's probably nice to avoid that if possible.

But it behooves you work the problem. 1 million anything at 1ms each, is 20 minutes of processing. At 500m, every nano-second wasted adds up to 8+ minutes extra of processing. You may well not care, but just demonstrating that at these scales "every little bit helps".

So, don't take our words for it, test different things to find what gives you the best result for your work set, and then go with that. Also consider excessive object creation, and avoiding that. Normally, I don't give it a second thought. Object creation is fast, but a nano-second is a nano-second.

If you're working in Java, and you don't REALLY need Unicode (i.e. you're working with single characters of the 0-255 range), I wouldn't use strings at all. I'd work with raw bytes. String are based on Java characters, which are UTF-16. Java Readers convert UTF-8 in to UTF-16 every. single. time. 500 million times. Yup! Another few nano-seconds. 8 nano-seconds adds an hour to your processing.

So, again, look in all the corners.

Or, don't, write it easy, fire it up, run it over the weekend and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

If each String has a unique identifier then retrieval is O(1) only in case of hashmaps.

I wouldn't suggest the first method because you are splitting every string for 450*500m, unless your order is one string for 500m times then on to the next. As Will said, appending numeric to strings then retrieving might seem straight forward but is not recommended.

So if your data is static (just the 450 strings) put them in a Hashmap and experiment it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashMap<Integer, String>.` Splitting a string to get the identifier is an expensive operation because it involves creating new Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you a convincing "right" answer, especially since you haven't provided all of the background / properties of the computation.  (For example, the average length of the strings could make a lot of difference.)

So I think your best bet would be to write a benchmark ... using the *actual* strings that you are going to be processing.

I'd also look for a way to extract and test the "unique integer identifier" that doesn't entail splitting the string.

Answer (score -1):

Splitting the string should work faster if you write your code well enough. In fact if you already have the int-id, I see no reason to send only the string and maintain a mapping.

Putting into `HashMap` would need hashing the incoming string every time. So you are basically comparing the performance of the hashing function vs the code you write to append (prepending might be a bit more tricky) on sending end and to parse on receiving end.

OTOH, only 450 strings aren't a big deal, and if you're into it, writing your own hashing algo/function would actually be the most elegant and performant.

Comment: Splitting the String will create two new Strings, and those will then have to be GCed.  Referencing a HashMap would be much cheaper.

Comment: @HotLicks, Read. "if you write your code well enough", "you already have the int-id", "writing your own hashing algo/function would actually be the most elegant and performant" and finally, arguing that that GC would take time is just too much for topic in discussion.

Comment: You can't have a discussion about Java performance and ignore GC.